# C++ simple 2D vector

Tags: c++, beginner, classes, coordinate-system

I'm brand new to cpp and tried implementing a simple Vector class that supports abs(), equality and addition operators. I just wanted a quick set of eyes to tell me if I'm doing anything egregious in my constructor/operators and finally their usage.

Note: the [[nodiscard]] was recommended by the clion IDE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Vector {
public:
    double x, y;
    [[nodiscard]] double abs() const {return sqrt(x*x + y*y);}

    // constructor
    Vector(double x, double y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    // add op
    Vector operator+(const Vector& b) {
        Vector vec(this->x, this->y);
        vec.x += b.x;
        vec.y += b.y;
        return vec;
    }

    // eq op
    bool operator==(const Vector& b) {
        if (this->x == b.x && this->y == b.y) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector vec = Vector(4, 8);
    Vector vec2 = Vector(3.2, 5.5);
    Vector vec3 = vec + vec2;
    bool equal = vec == vec2;
    bool equal2 = vec == Vector(4, 8);

    std::cout << equal << std::endl;
    std::cout << equal2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << vec3.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << vec.abs() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the add operator, you're currently constructing a brand new vector when you do `Vector vec(this->x, this->y)`, before manipulating the newly constructed vector's `x` and `y` values. If this is what you want to do, you can add the values in the constructor instead: `return Vector(x+other.x, y+other.y)`. You may, however, also want to implement and use the incremental add operator `+=`, where you instead just could add to `this->x` and `this->y` and return `*this`. If you do this you should also return by reference, i.e.:

```cpp
Vector& operator+=(const Vector& other) {
  this->x += x;
  this->y += y;
  return *this;
}
```

You probably want your `x` and `y` members to be private and not public. And use member initialisation - your constructor can be changed to

```cpp
Vector(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
```

Also consider that `if (condition) return true else return false` is the same as `return condition`, i.e. you can do

```cpp
    bool operator==(const Vector& other) {
        return (this->x == other.x && this->y == other.y);
    }
```

Finally, maybe have a look at some existing libraries that implement vectors (in 2 or 3 dimensions - shouldn't matter much). These should be able to give you some help or inspiration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, some of it is going over my head so I'll look some things up today and get back to you.

Comment: Using member initialization (rather than assigning in the constructor's body) does not enable RAII.  I don't see what RAII has to do with this class, at all.

Comment: You're right of course @JDługosz, don't know what I was thinking there.

Comment: I don’t see a reason to make x and y private. There is no class invariant to maintain, this no need to prevent the user from randomly changing their values. Making them private reduces the usefulness of the class.

Answer (score 5):

In `abs()`, we use global-namespace `sqrt`.  You probably get away with this on a platform where `<cmath>` also provides that, but to be truly portable, don't rely on that - use its full name `std::sqrt`.  Better still, we can use `std::hypot()`, which avoids potential problems when the sum of the squares exceeds the range of `double`.

The `[[nodiscard]]` annotation seems well-intentioned, but isn't really necessary - nobody is likely to use a `const` member function for side-effects and fail to use the result, and no harm comes from that, making the annotation arguably just clutter.  The real benefit is for functions such as `std::scanf()` where the return value tends to be overlooked by users.

---

In the constructor, we should prefer to *initialise* the members, rather than *assign* them in the body:

```
Vector(double x, double y)
    : x{x},
      y{y}
{
}
```

However, we don't need a constructor at all, if we're happy to have a default constructor as well.  We'll want our default constructor to create a useful default value - I'd recommend {0,0} - and we can achieve that by providing default values for `x` and `y`:

```
double x = 0;
double y = 0;
```

---

Consider providing a `+=` operator.  We can then use that to implement `+` as a non-member function:

```
    Vector& operator+=(const Vector& b) {
        x += b.x;
        y += b.y;
        return *this;
    }

// (outside the class)
Vector operator+(Vector a, const Vector& b) {
    return a += b;
}
```

Note that we accept `a` by value, so we can modify our copy of it, but `b` can be a const reference.

---

The equality operator should be `const`, and can be defaulted in current standard C++:

```
bool operator==(const Vector& b) const = default;
```

---

In the `main()` function, we're unnecessarily flushing each line with `std::endl`.  Plain newline (`\n`) is more efficient.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <cmath>

struct Vector
{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;

    bool operator==(const Vector& b) const = default;

    Vector& operator+=(const Vector& b) {
        x += b.x;
        y += b.y;
        return *this;
    }

    double abs() const
    {
        return std::hypot(x, y);
    }
};

Vector operator+(Vector a, const Vector& b) {
    return a += b;
}
```

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto vec = Vector{4, 8};
    auto vec2 = Vector{3.2, 5.5};
    auto vec3 = vec + vec2;
    bool equal = vec != vec2;
    bool equal2 = vec == Vector{4, 8};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << equal << '\n'
              << equal2 << '\n'
              << vec3.x << '\n'
              << vec.abs() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I think the recommendation to use a print of `\n` over `std::endl` merits a bit more explanation - is flushing always bad?

Comment: No worries @ades the flushing part I don't mind for this example. this is very useful thank you

Comment: Could you provide a link/source for how that equality 1 liner works, I have no understanding of why we can simply do const = default

Comment: This doesn't compile on clion due to there not being a constructor, why is not using the default constructor?

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos, have you set your compiler to accept a sufficiently modern version of C++?  It's a good idea to select the most recent version it can support; e.g. I generally use `g++ -std=c++20` when compiling with GCC.

Comment: i'm on clion and CMakelists.txt has set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
I'll try compiling manually (I'm on apple M1 so will be the apple LLVM version)

Comment: main.cpp:40:26: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Vector'

Comment: ❯ g++ -std=c++20 main.cpp

Comment: are you sure i don't need Vector(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}

Comment: Seems like it really should support aggregate initialisation as shown (and works from me with GCC).  As a workaround, just include the constructor that initialises the members, perhaps in a suitable `#ifdef` for your compiler.

Comment: [GCC but not Clang](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rbTr8nss7) - I guess one of those is wrong...

Comment: Try using curly braces:  `Vector vec2 {3.2, 5.5};`  In any case, what you wrote is kind of redundant naming the type twice!  If you _really_ want that form, use `auto` for the first occurance:  `auto vec2 = Vector {2.5,3.5};`.